# mathematica replacement rule subexpression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, rules, replace

I have using replacement rules:

First I have defined some simple formulas using SetDelayed

```
a:=b+c
d:=a/e
```

Evaluating the following equation gives a result as expected:

```
In[20]:= (d^2 + something)/(d - 1)
Out[20]= ((b+c)^2/e^2+something)/((b+c)/e-1)
```

But if I want to replace the "d" by another term, let's say "tmp", I get the following:

```
In[26]:= (d^2+something)/(d-1)//.d->tmp
Out[26]= ((b+c)^2/e^2+something)/(tmp-1)
```

It seems that the variable "d" is only replaced if it's not surrounded by a function like "Power". So the term `d^2` is not replaced by `tmp`.

So what am I doing wrong if I want `d` to be replaced each time it occurs during the steps of evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

In your `In[26]` the evaluator has rewritten `d` according to the rule you established for it before the `ReplaceRepeated` (which you've written as `//.`) sees it.

Mathematica's evaluator is quite greedy and `//.` has fairly low precedence so the expression to the left of `//.` in `In[26]` has been rewritten to

```
((b+c)^2/e^2+something)/(tmp-1)
```

before your replacement rule has a chance to run.  Since this expression contains no `d` the replacement rule `d->tmp` is not engaged.

You have a number of choices.

a) You could write a new expression for `d` such as `d:=tmp` or `d=tmp` in which case evaluating

```
(d^2+something)/(d-1)
```

will produce

```
(something + tmp^2)/(-1 + tmp)
```

b) You could delete the definition of `d` made by evaluating `d:=a/e` and simply use a replacement rule whenever you want to transform an expression including `d`.

c) You could study the definition and use of functions such as `Hold[]` and `HoldFirst[]` and those parts of the documentation which cover both Mathematica's usual evaluation process and how to modify it.

d) As usual with Mathematica, there will be other ways to achieve what you want, the best choice will depend on exactly what you are trying to do.

To answer your particular question *what am I doing wrong if I want d to be replaced each time it occurs during the steps of evaluation?*: you are defining the rewrite rule `d:=a/e` and putting it into the set of rules to be tried during the evaluation of any expression evaluated thereafter in your session.

**EDIT** in response to comment

`d:=a/e` isn't a temporary replacement, it's a definition which persists until removed or replaced or you close your session.  Generally, use rules (such as your `d->tmp`.  Of course, Mathematica being what it is you can assign rules to variables, eg

```
rule1 = d->a/e
```

and use them in the obvious way

```
expression /. rule1
```

You can define lists of rules

```
rule_list = {d->tmp, e->tmp2, f-> tmp3}
```

and so on.

Comment: First very thanks for your fast reply.
The background is that I have a number of different formulas which are combined into on final equation. To make some experiments with this equation, I tried to temporarily set some partial formulas (like d:=a/e) to a constant variable without overwriting the term of d. That's why I tried to use rules as temporarily replacements. Using the Hold-Functions was also an idea but didn't help me. Do you have an idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I played a little bit with the Hold[]-Functions and got a solution that worked for me.

First, I Hold every SetDelayed-term

```
a:=Hold[b+c]
d:=Hold[a/e]
```

Constructing the complete equation, I use the following commands to substitute several variables before computation. Therefore I use the Nest[] function to substitute them in different levels:

```
In[338]:= expression=Hold[(d^2+something)/(d-1)];
Nest[ReleaseHold[#//.HoldPattern[d]->tmp]&,expression,10]

Out[339]= (something+tmp^2)/(tmp-1)
```

This gives me the result I want and works with deeper levels of substitution.